# How can I encourage more proactive players to distribute information they have gathered to other involved players?

Tags: player-communication, freeform, play-by-chat

I am preparing to run a larger plot via a [MUSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUSH) that will involve several scenes, but the players between the scenes might change, so not everybody will have the same information when joining scenes. This also means that not everybody is present for all scenes, and not everybody missing a scene will be bothered to read the logs. On the other hand, some players have characters that reasonably can and will gather extra information in the time between scenes, either by contacting me via a `page` or in some intermediate scene.

To make answering easier, some additional information about the communication on MUSH-freeform RPGs in general:

- Players generally don't rely on that others have additional communication paths among each other than the MUSH itself.
- Most MUSHes offer an `@mail` (internal, stored mails) and `page` (instant message) system, possibly also group channels, in addition to the local place, where one can speak (`say`), emote (`@emit` & `:`) and talk `OOC`-ly.
- Information is generally not saved unless it is either saved by a player or sent as @mail. Pages to offline users get dropped.
- Logs on MUSHes generally only contain the local results of the `say` and `@emit` commands. OOC talk and pages (should) *never* appear in published logs, but might in some player's private ones. Channel-talk usually has to be manually added to logs too.

As a somewhat crucial part, it is very frowned upon to use information acquired only via metagaming - one has to provide a reason to know about the stuff to be able to use them IC-ly, and if it is "Hank told Mark about X".

I am willing to distribute this extra information to players asking for them and write up primers for scenes so people can be brought basically up to speed, but I am worried that the information distributed to the asking players is not brought into the RP by the players that got them but lost in the mills.

How can I encourage the more proactive players to distribute those pieces of information to the other involved players via IC means?

Comment: Are all the players working together to accomplish something, or are they rivals with each other, and people might be gathering information to use against their rivals?

Comment: @Glazius while some might be rivals, The information I can give out are only concerning the plot so can't really be used to fuel rivalries really.

Answer (score 1):

## Player-initiated summaries benefit everyone.

Since you're presenting information to be used cooperatively, having a player do the summary has benefits for everyone involved in the process.

- It helps **everyone who didn't know** for obvious reasons; now they have more information.
- It helps **you, the gamerunner** by telling you what the player thinks is important and worth focusing on in the information you presented, helping you run a game that can better play to the things they find interesting. They'll also probably interleave their own conclusions and concerns about the information they found, which can help to inspire you going forward.
- Lastly, since you're intending this information to be used cooperatively, giving the summary benefits **the player giving it**. Not so much right when they're giving it, but, well. If you presented information to them that you intended to be important and memorable, but their summary doesn't mention it at all, that lets you know it didn't stick. I mean, when you gave them this information, you didn't tear open the fourth wall and stick your head through and say "this is important, remember it for later!", right? You presented it as a thing that existed in the world and hoped you communicated its importance successfully. So having a player summarize what they know gives you an opportunity to also **tell them what they missed**.

That last one will probably be the biggest draw, from a player perspective. Getting the gamerunner to "check their work", and such.

### "Cool, what's that look like?" feat. Universal GM Spackle

Those five words: "Cool, what's that look like?" are an excellent bridge from out-of-character description to in-character action. They turn you from High Judge GM the Merciless demanding a description to a curious friend who wants to hear you talk about your character.

Just be sure to act like a curious friend, too. I mean, don't use it after every sentence, just when your actual human brain can't understand how they just, for instance, explained the unified front of secret ape police from the crystal dimension and time-traveling birds from Jupiter in plain view in a coffeehouse.

But overall, saying "cool, what's that look like?", and asking followup questions until you're satisfied is a solid way to get people talking, if not *as* their characters, then at least *about* them.

Comment: Since it sounds like PvP is also an aspect of this game, player-driven summaries also provide an opportunity for the player writing the summary to control the narrative and to ingratiate themselves to other players by providing a universally useful service, both of which are also benefits in a potentially competitive game.

Comment: Ahhh, as you elaborated I realized that my question missed a crucial 3 words: via IC means.Stuff like at least saying ICly "Peter brings Hank up to speed, telling him X, Y and Z"